# Postman Test script using csv file

Tags: postman

I have a Json response from a request which contains address fields like addressLine1, addressLine2, city,postalCode and all displayed under text field.

I have a csv file where I store the values and have a Postman test script which checks if the response contains the expected value from the csv file.

CSV file has the following data:

[image]

In the test script I do the assertion like the below :

```
     pm.expect(response.address.text).to.eql(myCSV.addressLine1 + ", " + myCSV.addressLine2 + " " +myCSV.city+ ", " + myCSV.postalCode);
    })
```

It works fine for all the iterations except the last one where there is no addressLine2 field and the assertion fails because there is an extra space

Assert address text | AssertionError: expected '13 Yarrow Street, City 58, 7854' to deeply equal '13 Yarrow Street,  City 58, 7854'

Has someone handled something similar through their code?

Comment: is the assertion messsage correct ?

Comment: 3 Yarrow Street, City 58 are the space between this two strings are same in actual and expected ?

Answer (score 0):

Your `myCSV.addressLine2 + " "` is too simple-minded. If `myCSV.addressLine2` happens to be empty, you do *not* want to append that extra space. The space is what constitutes the difference between the response address text and the expression in parentheses.